# Oracle - On Delete/On Update

Tags: database, oracle

I have another table named Users and when i execute this code down here:

```
create table Borrow(
bookID int,
memberID int,
dayOfBorrowed date not null,
dayToReturn date not null,
giverUser int not null,
CONSTRAINT check_dayToReturn check(dayToReturn>dayOfBorrowed),
primary key (bookID, memberID),
foreign key (bookID) references Books(bookID) on delete cascade,
foreign key (memberID) references Members(memberID) on delete cascade, 
foreign key (giverUser) references Users(userID) on update no action on delete no action);
```

I am getting this error

```
> Error starting at line : 72 in command - create table Borrow( bookID
> int, memberID int, dayOfBorrowed date not null, dayToReturn date not
> null, giverUser int not null, CONSTRAINT check_dayToReturn
> check(dayToReturn>dayOfBorrowed), primary key (bookID, memberID),
> foreign key (bookID) references Books(bookID) on delete cascade,
> foreign key (memberID) references Members(memberID) on delete cascade,
> foreign key (giverUser) references Users(userID) on update no action on delete no action)
> Error report - ORA-00905: missing keyword
> 00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
> *Cause:    
> *Action:
```

Can someone please explain to me what i have done wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Let's [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/clauses002.htm#SQLRF52180):

[image: references_clause]

```
REFERENCES [ schema. ] object [ (column [, column ]...) ]
  [ON DELETE { CASCADE | SET NULL } ]
```

In other words, Oracle doesn't have the `ON UPDATE` feature thus `ON UPDATE NO ACTION` is not even needed.

P.S. You may want to find an tool with builtin SQL parsing:

[image: JetBrains]

Answer (score 0):

there's no `on update` option for `foreign key references`.

The problem stems from this referencing (last) row.

Remove

> `on update no action on delete no action`

part.

You might use `on delete cascade` or `on delete set null`, but not `on delete no action` clause.

Comment: also when i'm using just on delete no action i'm getting same error !!

Comment: @BlendMexhuani since you don't need to emphasize "on delete no action" clause(has no sense).

Comment: but i don't want my records in this table to be deleted just because i delete that user

Comment: If you want child records to remain when the parent record is removed, you need to either not have the foreign key, or use a "soft" delete - i.e. retain the parent record, but have a column to say that the record is no longer in use.

Comment: @BlendMexhuani ok, then you needn't to tell `on delete no action`, since that's default. i.e. if there's no `on delete` clause, nothing will be deleted when you remove foreign constraint.